# Why did someone at the airport ask for my passport and write my info in a book?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, officials

I’m 18 this year and I’m going to Korea for the third time. Once last year, twice this year. This time, I got a stamp on my flight ticket: it was stamped when I transferred from a domestic flight to an international flight. And then just shortly after that, when I scanned my bag, the officer asked me for my passport. She took it and wrote my info in a book, and there were other names but I couldn’t focus because I just wondered if I’d done anything wrong.

Maybe it was a wrong move but I asked if there was a problem, and the officer said that she only picked them randomly and not to worry. I’m going to meet my boyfriend and I’m just nervous I might not get to meet him.

Answer (score 5):

This is not uncommon in some countries: I've been asked to show my ID card once at security at Kutaisi airport.

It was a random check, and they may note down specific details about you. In other words, no cause for concern.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to answer this conclusively without asking someone who works at the airport.  But, don't worry, there are many, many valid reasons that have nothing to do with you.  Some possibilities:

- She was merely verifying you have valid travel docs, but is required
  to log them to demonstrate she actually did verify them.
- They're collecting random document numbers to validate the performance or
  operations of some other systems.
- They're timing random travelers through the exit/entry process.

Such things happen all the time.  If you were in any 'trouble' they would not let you just walk away.